# htaccess rewrite image link into a short one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

please I want to rewrite the image link into a new short one in the adress bar..
my web site contains many images in different locations.
so I want to display all images as it was in the same directory:

**Exp:**

```
domain.com/dir1/dir2/img1.jpg => domain.com/img1.jpg

domain.com/dir/img2.gif => domain.com/img2.gif

domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/img3.png => domain.com/img3.png
```

is it possible ?! or else I have to upload all images in the main directory with index.php ??

Comment: This is not going to be easy, as Apache won't search recursively for matches.  It would be possible with _many_ `RewriteCond` to determine if a file exists in each directory, but you would have to have one for each directory path as far as I know.

Comment: at least, if you can, give me an example how can I rewrite an url from domain.com/dir/img.jpg  TO  domain.com/img.jpg

Comment: I added the simple example as requested, and also some direction on how to make it work for your tree structure...

Answer (score 0):

To write all images from the root into `dir`, use the following.  You may add other image extensions into the group `(jpe?g|png|gif)` as needed.  Use this if you are able to move all your images into `dir/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([^.]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ dir/$1.$2 [L]
```

In order to make your original idea work, the only method I can think of would be to use a `RewriteCond` which checks every possible directory for the given image.  It will fall through each rule until one matches:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Does the file exist in dir1? (-f)
RewriteCond dir1/${REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^.]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ dir1/$1.$2 [L]
# Does it exist in dir1/sub1 ?
RewriteCond dir1/sub1/${REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^.]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ dir1/sub1/$1.$2 [L]
# Does it exist in dir2/sub1/sub2 ?
RewriteCond dir1/sub1/${REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^.]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ dir2/sub1/sub2/$1.$2 [L]
# And on and on for each directory which may have images....
```

Clearly this is not easily maintainable and if you have more than 5-6 directories it is completely out of hand.  I just don't know another way to make apache search recursively.

#### Update after comments:

If you need to first forcibly redirect an image in any directory to appear in the root inside the browser, as in:

```
example.com/uploads/0cfa524e_201446.jpg --> example.com/0cfa524e_201446.jpg
```

place the following rules *before* those rules I have above. It will force a redirect, and after redirection, one of the subsequent rules should match and serve the file.

```
# Redirect any image file which is requested _inside_ a directory to appear at the root
RewriteRule ^/?.+/([^.]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.$2 [L,R=301]

#... then add all the rules from above.
```

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem...
for example, I have this image link
mydomain .com/uploads/0cfa524e_201446.jpg
I want it to display without showing the dir name in the link, just like that
mydomain .com/0cfa524e_201446.jpg

Comment: @MedHossam see addition above.